# Github - Como criar uma segunda fork de um determinado repositório?

Tags: git, github

Digamos que eu possua um fork do repositorio `user\original` como `meuser\original`.

Se caso eu queira criar um novo fork do primeiro, como eu faço? No github ao clicar em criar um fork novo ele apenas redireciona para o fork existente.

Como ficaria se eu renomear o fork `meuser\original` como `meuser\original-OLD` e queira criar um novo fork `meuser\original` com as atualizações mais recentes?

Answer (score 1):

Acabei encontrando um artigo sobre como fazer isso.

O procedimento é chamado de "Dupliforking" e o o link do artigo é esse:
https://github.com/enyojs/enyo/wiki/Dupliforking

Abaixo uma tradução:

Suponhamos que você queira criar o repo "MillionDollars".

Clone o repositorio original (aqui o bootplate) e cd até a pasta.

```
git clone https://github.com/enyojs/bootplate.git MillionDollars

cd MillionDollars
```

Inicialize os subrepositórios.

```
git submodule update --init
```

Vá até o site do GitHub e crie um novo repositório com o nome escolhido ("MillionDollars").

Aponte o clone do bootplate para o seu novo repositorio (Esse passo altera de onde as commits são baixadas e enviadas)

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<your user name>/MillionDollars.git
```

Usuários de editores de texto podem também diretamente editar o arquivo `MillionDollars/.git/config`:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:<your user name>/MillionDollars.git
    ...
```

Dê um push no seu repositório

Tudo pronto!

Answer (score 0):

Em fez de criares um fork, porque não crias um `branch` no mesmo repositório em vez de um fork, preserva todas as commits anteriores, depois podes fazer merge do que queres com o master.

Edit: Removido o link, após ter percebido a ideia real da pergunta :)

Comment: É que eu gostaria de preservar as commits do repo original, e fazer um merge das modificações do original pra fork agora é improvável pela quantidade de código mexido.

E nesse link a pergunta fala sobre fazer um fork de um fork, o que não é meu caso. Eu queria era fazer um segundo fork do repositorio original, sem relação com o fork existente

Comment: Okay, pensei que era um fork de um fork que já tinhas, penso mesmo assim que o branch faz tudo o que queres, preserva o que ja tens depois podes fazer merge entre branch e master

Comment: E como ficariam as linhas de comando para fazer isso? Sou leigo nessa parte.

Comment: É relativamente fácil, podes fazer merge no site, com o software ou com o git bash http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601931/best-and-safest-way-to-merge-a-git-branch-into-master